# Python tkinter key-binding to all subsequent widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to bind to events (one for Ctrl+Z and one for Ctrl+Y) to a python tkinter form that is very complex (the root has many child frames and those also have, so binding the event to each of those would be very annoying and redundant). I hoped there was a method to bind the key to the root so that even when my focus is inside on of the child widgets the binding will trigger. What I tried so far is this:

```
def _init_gui(self, root):
        """ Initializes all members of the gui"""
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, root) #Superclass init
        self.root = root
        width, height = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()

        #Most of the code is left out because it is not neccessary

        self.root.bind_all("Control-z", lambda _: self.undo())
        self.root.bind_all("Control-y", lambda _: self.redo())
```

However this does not seem to work. Is there any proper solution to this? (I also tried the bind-Method with the same lack of result)

Comment: `bind` or `bind_all` should work for that. Make sure you use the angle brackets in the command, and lambda is not needed here:  `self.root.bind("<Control-z>", self.undo)`

Comment: Thank you, silly me... However lambda is needed since an event is passed and the signature of undo and redo does not take arguments obviously.

Comment: So add it to the signature. The standard form would be `def undo(self, event=None):` so that it can be called from bind or normally. If you want to add the capability to call it from trace as well: `def undo(self, *args):`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't properly specifying the event. The proper event names are `"<Control-z>"` and `"<Control-y>"` (take note of the `<` and `>`).

Other than that, `bind_all` is exactly what you want.

There's also no need to use `lambda`. It's only useful in one specific situation, and this isn't it. Just provide a reference to a function that accepts an argument for the event object that tkinter automatically passes to the callback. If you also want to call the function directly, give the event parameter a null default.

For example:

```
def undo(self, event=None):
    ...
def redo(self, event=None):
    ...

self.root.bind_all("<Control-y>", self.undo)
self.root.bind_all("<Control-z>", self.redo)
```